# Changing / ignoring TestNG annotations in Gradle using build or environment parameters?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng

I have a unique situation where I have to set `alwaysRun = true` on my setup and teardown methods for one browser only (IE8) due to the way Selenium and the current framework handle things. I could go into my reasoning but I'll just skip to the question for now:

Is there a way that can get the `alwaysRun = true` tags to be ignored if I pass in a particular system property or somehow parameterize these annotations so they're only interpreted as `true` under certain circumstances? I'm using TestNG, Gradle, and Java driving Selenium 2.

Here's the bulk of my base test class (extended by all my tests):

```
   @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void suiteSetup() throws Exception {
        if (REMOTE_DRIVER) {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
            if (BROWSER.equals("firefox")) {
                capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            } else if (BROWSER.equals("internetExplorer")) {
                capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
            } else if (BROWSER.equals("chrome")) {
                capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Browser type unsupported");
            }
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
                    new URL("http://" + SELENIUM_HOST + ":" + SELENIUM_PORT + "/wd/hub"),
                    capabilities);
            driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
            //  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        } else {
            if (BROWSER.equals("firefox")) {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            } else if (BROWSER.equals("chrome")) {
                String path;
                if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
                    path = "lib/chromedriver.exe";
                } else {
                    path = "lib/chromedriver";
                }
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                // on linux, you may have to uncomment these, I couldn't get it to work without it
                //ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                //options.setBinary(new File("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser"));
                //driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            } else if (BROWSER.equals("internetExplorer")) {
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Browser type unsupported");
            }
        }
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void loadLoginPage() {
        try {
            driver.get("http://" + WEB_SERVER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                // some types of errors may leave a hanging "are you sure you want to leave this page" dialog
                // accept if it exists, ignore it otherwise
                driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            } catch (WebDriverException ex) {
                // no alert
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void testTearDown() {
        try {
            // some types of errors may leave a hanging "are you sure you want to leave this page" dialog
            // accept if it exists, ignore it otherwise
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            // no alert
        }
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void suiteTearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Without going nuts and refactoring this entire project, what would be the best way for me to go about "using" simply `@BeforeClass` for all my runs except IE which requires `@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)` (and the rest of the setup and teardown methods) with the least amount of headache? I've considered many options but they're all massive undertakings and I have a feeling there has to be a simple solution out there.

Comment: And "where" do you know that you use IE8? At what level?

Comment: Main question is whether TestNG itself provides a way to set this flag dynamically, rather than hardcoding it in the annotation. If not, Gradle won't be able to do anything about it.

Comment: @fge It's determined at build time using Gradle that IE8 is being used by running a task that passes the BROWSER=internetExplorer system property in.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I've found this: http://testng.org/doclava/reference/org/testng/IAnnotationTransformer2.html but not sure if that's getting a little too complex for my situation.

Comment: Sounds like it could be your best chance.